# PHP Copy/Send Files into Correct Folder

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot of files that are named like this:

`TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112
TRK# WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152
TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714`

I would like to send each file to its own folder.

Example:

`TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112`
would go inside folder 112

also,

`TRK# WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152` would not go anywhere because TRK# is empty/missing or it's **not a number**. IF ITS NOT A NUMBER SKIP IT.

and

`TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714`  would go into folder 115

Comment: This is going to be primarily a regular expressions task. What do you know about regular expressions?

Comment: @Goose Thanks for your time. bishop is helping me also but it looks like we are running into an os issue. I think he has a very promising solution but it's not working yet. If you can look over it that would be really great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to pull out the number, then you can use [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to make the actual filesystem copy:

```
function doCopy($file) {
    preg_match('/TRK\s*#\s*(\d+)/', $file, $matches);
    if (empty($matches[1])) { // no number, skip it
        return false;
    }
    $folder = dirname($file) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $matches[1];
    if (! is_dir($folder)) { // target directory doesn't exist: make it
        mkdir($folder);
    }
    $target = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($file);
    echo "Copying '$file' into '$target'" . PHP_EOL;
    return copy($file, $target); // actually copy now
}
```

Then a loop over your files, using this function, would go like:

```
$files = [
    'TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112',
    'TRK# WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152',
    'TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714',
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $copied = doCopy($file);
    if (! $copied) {
        echo "Did not copy $file" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The "magic" is in the regular expression [`/TRK\s*#\s*(\d+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/vhJBVk/1), which says to match:

1. the literal string "TRK",
2. followed by any number of spaces,
3. followed by the literal string "#",
4. followed by any number of spaces,
5. followed by any number of digits -- while capturing the matched digits.

We then check if there are matched digits -- the `empty` test -- and do a copy into a directory named with that matched value. We have to be careful when juggling paths. First, the target directory must exist. Second, we need to ensure that `copy` can find the original file in the appropriate directory, and that we give it a target that includes the file name. Well over half the logic goes to this overhead.

---

Example run on a Linux machine:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/'TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112.pdf'
$ touch test/'TRK# WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152.pdf'
$ touch test/'TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714.pdf'
$ cat example.php
<?php

function doCopy($file) {
    preg_match('/TRK\s*#\s*(\d+)/', $file, $matches);
    if (empty($matches[1])) {
        return false;
    }
    $folder = dirname($file) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $matches[1];
    if (! is_dir($folder)) {
        mkdir($folder);
    }
    $target = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($file);
        echo "Copying '$file' into '$target'" . PHP_EOL;
    return copy($file, $target);
}

$files = glob('test/*.pdf');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $copied = doCopy($file);
    if (! $copied) {
        echo "Did not copy $file" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$ php example.php
Copying 'test/TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112.pdf' into 'test/112/TRK# 112 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112.pdf'
Copying 'test/TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714.pdf' into 'test/115/TRK# 115 WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714.pdf'
Did not copy test/TRK# WeekDay# 5 From# BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152.pdf
$ tree test/
test/
├── 112
│   └── TRK#\ 112\ WeekDay#\ 5\ From#\ BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112.pdf
├── 115
│   └── TRK#\ 115\ WeekDay#\ 5\ From#\ BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714.pdf
├── TRK#\ 112\ WeekDay#\ 5\ From#\ BOB___Tender_P582895zdf112.pdf
├── TRK#\ 115\ WeekDay#\ 5\ From#\ BOB___Tender_P582895zdf714.pdf
└── TRK#\ WeekDay#\ 5\ From#\ BOB___Tender_P588895zdf152.pdf
```